# Initializing objects or lists in asp.net mvc site and garbage collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, garbage-collection

I am curious if the following implementation can cut down garbage colection.  I have started doing initializations of my classes for properties so I dont have to check NULL when using them.  My question is, does this cause more garbage collection to occur because its not NULL anymore?  I want to get my GC down and this looks like a good option.

**Property**

```
public List<ScheduleVenueTravelTimeModel> TravelTimes { get; set; }
```

**Property With Initialization**

```
public List<ScheduleVenueTravelTimeModel> TravelTimes { get; set; } = new List<ScheduleVenueTravelTimeModel>();
```

**Constructors**

```
public ScheduleVenueLocationModel()
{
    TravelTimes = new List<ScheduleVenueTravelTimeModel>();
}
```

Comment: If an empty list is causing memory issues you have bigger problems. I'm pretty sure you're looking at the wrong place to optimize your code.

Comment: I am not saying that it is, but I am asking if I have millions of objects a day initialization like this would it be a best practice not to do this.

Comment: I would say best practice is to use the code that is most readable and safe, where you don't have millions of null checks everywhere. Instead optimize for example lists which are not initialized with a correct size(if you know it beforehand) but with the default constructor that uses a doubling algorithm on `Add`. There are many more ways to prevent unnecessary memory usage but your "optimization" is not a good way.

Comment: Not sure what this means `Instead optimize for example lists which are not initialized with a correct size(if you know it beforehand) but with the default constructor that uses a doubling algorithm on Add.`

Comment: So dont init like I am doing, but do it when I work with the list and init to the exact size.

Comment: If you know the exact size when you fill it, then yes.  But this default initialization doesn't hurt, it just hurts when you add items to it without re-initializing it to the correct size first. If you add 1025 items, the list capacity will be already 2048, so you are wasting memory.